# TypeORM select data from nested relations

Tags: sql, typescript, orm, typeorm

Using

```
await this.budgetRepository.createQueryBuilder("budget")
  .leftJoinAndSelect("budget.contact", "contact")
  .leftJoinAndSelect("contact.photo", "contactPhoto")
  .getMany();
```

I get a list with objects like this:

```
Budget {
   id: 1,
   unnecessary_property1: something,
   contact: Contact {
      unnecessary_property2: something,
      photo: Photo {
         unnecessary_property3: something,
         url: "url.com"
      },
   },
}
```

But I want to select only the necessary properties in the nested objects (relations) and get a list of objects like this:

```
Budget {
   id: 1,
   contact: Contact {
      photo: Photo {
         url: "url.com"
      },
   },
}
```

How is that possible with TypeORM?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is possible but we have to select everything manually with `.select()`

```
await this.budgetRepository.createQueryBuilder("budget")
  .leftJoinAndSelect("budget.contact", "contact")
  .leftJoinAndSelect("contact.photo", "contactPhoto")
  .select(['budget.id', 'contactPhoto.url']
  .getMany();
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're using repository pattern that you will be achieve the similar result with:

```
await this.budgetRepository.find({
  relations: ["contact", "contact.photo"]
  select: {
    contactfield1: true,
    contactfield2: true,
    photo: {
      phototfield1: true,
      phototfield2: true,
    }
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You would have to use the `.select()` function and pass the given properties you want for each entity.

for your example:

```js
const user = await createQueryBuilder("budget")
    .leftJoinAndSelect("budget.contact", "contact")
    .leftJoinAndSelect("contact.photo", "contactPhoto")
    .select([/* everything from budget */, 'contact.photo.url'....]) // added selection
    .getMany();
```

Comment: Unfortunatly, this does not work

Comment: i've updated the selection function to add the missing 'contact' before 'photo.url'